# Fragment ID in URL Not Working

Tags: html

I am using Microsoft Internet Explorer version 8 on Windows 7.
I have a HTML document that contains fragment IDs.
When I open Internet Explorer and enter the URL for my HTML page and include a fragment ID in the entered URL, the page is displayed but **not** at the requested part.
Below is the first part of my HTML document. Note that the document is very large and contains many fragment IDs. What is listed below is just a small part of my document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" lang="iw">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Lots of lines of text -->
<h2 id="George%20Best">George Best</h2>
```

I use the following URL:

```
file:///C:/HTML/MyPage.html#George%20Best
```

The page is displayed somewhere in the middle of the document, but nowhere near the heading "George Best".

Note that if I enter the following URL, the page is displayed at the top:

```
file:///C:/HTML/MyPage.html
```

Then if I manually append the fragment ID to the end of the URL, the display readjusts and the correct section of the document is displayed.
I believe I am missing something but I don't know what.
I am hoping that someone reading this will be able to enlighten me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the fragment ID but you're not url encoding the reference. Try this instead.

```
file:///C:/HTML/MyPage.html#George%2520Best
```

%25 is the url encoding for the % sign.