# Internet Explorer / Edge not sending fragment with URL

Tags: html, internet-explorer, fragment, microsoft-edge, hashcode

I am currently developing a website my company needs to deploy on the most significant browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Edge).

The website consists of a single index.html page, with a   whose content is being replaced depending on the hash code. That means when I ask for index.html#102, the content of the div gets replaced with, say, contents[102].

My problem is : when asking for 'file:///.../index.html#102' (the website will be stored locally), Internet Explorer (10, 11) and Edge get rid of the #102 and actually ask for 'file:///.../index.html'. So I basically end up on the homepage every single time... Chrome, Firefox and Safari all ask for 'index.html#102' (awesome !), IE and Edge are the only ones deleting the '#102'.

Do you happen to know why ? I spent my whole day looking for an answer, and trying the solutions provided for similar issues ([Keeping URL Fragments when redirecting in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168031/keeping-url-fragments-when-redirecting-in-internet-explorer), [Fragment ID in URL Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380292/fragment-id-in-url-not-working), https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/428644/url-hash-gets-removed-in-ie-after-redirect, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/05/16/url-fragments-and-redirects/) but none of them worked.

I understand hash codes are local and will never be sent to servers : is it possible that IE / Edge think my request is sent to a server ?

I am a beginner developer, trying to help the company on those issues, this is not my full-time job, so I reckon I might have missed a few critical pieces of info for you to help me = feel free to ask for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the form tag add attribute `onsubmit="window.location.reload()"` for only IE

or you can add it with jQuery `$(yourfoemid).attr('onsubmit',window.location.reload());`

or you can write it on `document.ready`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer TylerH ! 
Unfortunately, this did not work as Internet Explorer does not even ask for the right page ! The only way I managed to get through was by creating multiple files (e.g. index102.html) that would automatically redirect to the original ones (e.g. index.html#102). I am aware it is ugly, but at least it works :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62917034/13907595) helps you after 2 years.

Posting this to save time for someone who's facing the similar issue. Hope they won't struggle like me with the same issue again.

#### Posting working solution for me

We use `SiteMinder` authentication in our application.

I figured out that after successful authentication, `SiteMinder` is doing `302 redirection` to user requested application page by using **login form hidden variable `value`** (where it stores user requested URL `/myapp/` - `without hash fragment` since it won't be sent to the server) with name similar to `redirect`. Sample form below

[image: Sample login form]

Since `redirect` hidden variable **value** contains only `/myapp/` without hash fragment and it's a 302 redirect, the hash fragment is automatically removed by IE even before coming to our application and whatever the solutions we are trying in our application code are not working out.

IE is redirecting to `/myapp/` only and it is landing on default home page of our app `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/home`.

Have wasted almost a day to figure out this behavior.

#### The solution is:

Have changed the **login form** hidden variable (`redirect`) **value** to hold the hash fragment by
appending `window.location.hash` along with existing value. Similar to below code

```js
$(function () {
  var $redirect = $('input[name="redirect"]');
  $redirect.val($redirect.val() + window.location.hash);
});
```

After this change, the `redirect` hidden variable is storing user requested URL value as `/myapp/#/pending/requests` and `SiteMinder` is redirecting it to `/myapp/#/pending/requests` in IE.

**The above solution is working fine in all the three browsers `Chrome, Firefox and IE`.**

Thanks to @AlexFord for the [detailed explanation and providing solution](https://chevtek.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect) to this issue.