# URL fragment removed by IE after 302 login redirect

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, single-page-application, http-status-code-302, siteminder

We use **SiteMinder** authentication in our application.

If app user tries to navigate to a particular page `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/pending/requests` in our app via direct URL or via bookmarked URL, `SiteMinder` will redirect to a `login page` via 302 redirect similar to `http://ourapp.com/login?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fourapp.com%2Fmyapp%2F#/pending/requests` asking for user to enter credential in a **login form**. After successful authentication, user should be redirected to our app and land on the requested page(`/pending/requests`).

It's working absolutely fine in `Chrome` and `Firefox`. When it comes to IE it's landing on `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/home` (default landing page) instead of `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/pending/requests`.

I have tried various solutions provided in `google search results` in our app code like,

- Removing `<base>` tag in `index.html`
- Adding below lines of code at top of the page

```js
// setting location back
window.location = window.location;
```

```js
// setting location hash back
window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
```

- Few other solutions similar to above

Though [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283395/url-hash-is-persisting-between-redirects) perfectly makes sense,

I still want to `preserve the URL hash fragment in IE even it's 3xx redirect` for my requirement...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering my own Question

I figured out that after successful authentication, `SiteMinder` is doing `302 redirection` to user requested application page by using **login form hidden variable `value`** (where it stores user requested URL `/myapp/` - `without hash fragment` since it won't be sent to the server) with name similar to `redirect`. Sample form below

[image: Sample login form]

Since `redirect` hidden variable **value** contains only `/myapp/` without hash fragment and it's a 302 redirect, the hash fragment is automatically removed by IE even before coming to our application and whatever the solutions we are trying in our application code are not working out.

IE is redirecting to `/myapp/` only and it is landing on default home page of our app `https://ourapp.com/myapp/#/home`.

Have wasted almost a day to figure out this behavior.

#### The solution is:

Have changed the **login form** hidden variable (`redirect`) **value** to hold the hash fragment by
appending `window.location.hash` along with existing value. Similar to below code

```js
$(function () {
  var $redirect = $('input[name="redirect"]');
  $redirect.val($redirect.val() + window.location.hash);
});
```

After this change, the `redirect` hidden variable is storing user requested URL value as `/myapp/#/pending/requests` and `SiteMinder` is redirecting it to `/myapp/#/pending/requests` in IE.

**The above solution is working fine in all the three browsers `Chrome, Firefox and IE`.**

Thanks to @AlexFord for the [detailed explanation and providing solution](https://chevtek.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect) to this issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub project that demonstrates the POST behavior in IE vs. Chrome/FF without SiteMinder?  I would like to view the issue and compare it.

Comment: Apparently, I don't. It's company's **internal application issue** and I have solved it this way after little struggle. Checkout [this question and links posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51734295/13907595) in it. Irrespective of authentication flow tools (Not only `SiteMinder`), **IE** exhibits this behavior upon **multiple 302 redirects**. Hope it helps.